# Querying Access from SQL Server

Tags: sql, ms-access, openrowset

I have a large query that is built in SQL server and I need to query a table that is in an Access database. Is there any way to do this without using OPENROWSET() which is disabled by my DBA? I can't figure out the import wizard and copy pasting the actual rows into a temporary table won't work bc it's over 50k rows.

I have a bad feeling the only solution is creating a linked table to SQL server from Access and rewriting my query.

Comment: Why aren't you using Access to interface with SQLServer? What are you using as interface to SQLServer?

Comment: You (one) can connect the Access database file in SQL Server as a _Linked Server_, but I doubt you have been granted the rights to perform such a step.

Comment: We usually use Management Studio but this specific table was in Access. We ended up having to set up pass-through and rewrite the query